# Will eating candy with a lower ph than the stomach increase stomach acidity in the short term?

Tags: ph, stomach

The average stomach ph is 2.5. 
Some [candies](https://www.artofmoderndentistry.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/ph-candy-254x500.png) have a ph that is lower (more acidic) than that. 
Will eating candy with a lower ph than the stomach increase stomach acidity in the short term?

Comment: Do you have a specific concern about this (your link was about the effect of acidic candy on teeth.) Note that the candy on that list that I'm familiar with is sour (likely due to high citric acid content). Have you researched how sour candy might affect the stomach (you might get an answer right there)? Some background research is a requirement on this site. Thanks.

Comment: Well, it works for antacids so...

Comment: @DKNguyen - It works with antacids partly because antacids don't ellicit a response that counters the substance increasing the pH (well, Ca++ does cause a slight increase in acid secretion, but it's not clinically significant; it still neutralizes more acid than it stimulates secretion of.) I'm surprised at how limited this view is.

Comment: @anongoodnurse And on my end I am surprised why you choose to continue to going around pointing out why others are wrong but then choose not to also simply provide a full answer if you know what's going on.

Comment: @DKNguyen - We aren't *supposed* to answer questions which lack research. I am happy to provide answers to anyone demonstrating even a bit of research, and have always been. We are also "not supposed to answer in comments". That doesn't stop people from comment, posting the wrong answer. Which is worse? Posting the wrong answer in a comment/answer or steering readers to the more correct scenario? This is what I try to do. Way too often, people guess at an answer in comments which is completely wrong.

Comment: Ah, I see. So that's why you are witholding an answer. Understood.

Comment: @DKNguyen - Do you? Or are you being sarcastic, because I can't tell from those written words.

Comment: @anongoodnurse Not being sarcastic.

Comment: @DKNguyen - OK, thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

That's a simple closed chemical system, none of the fluid and reactant escapes, so yes, it will lower the pH of the stomach fluid, to add fluid with a lower pH.

Comment: No source? "...to add fluid with a lower pH." The candy isn't a fluid, it dissolves in saliva. Please note that sour candy causes **copious** salivary secretions, with a pH of around 6.7. Does that affect your answer? It should. As with other organs, the stomach has a degree of homeostatic mechanisms.

Comment: realize that with a mouth on one end and an anus on the other, and many, many glands throughout, that the GI tract is not "a simple closed chemical system"